# Having trouble using aggregate and boolean in a Case Statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, max, case, window-functions

I have a table in PostgreSQL with 3 fields : ebtyp, erdat,  v_no.

Input :

[image]

I want to apply: `(case when ebtyp='LA' and erdat=max(erdat) then vbeln end) as Inbound_delivery_number`

I do not want to filter or use a where clause for LA/AB as I do not want to eliminate any rows.

Output :

[image]

I tried this but its not working :

```
select case 
        when ebtyp='LA' and erdat=max(erdat) 
             then v_no OVER (PARTITION BY ebtyp) 
      end as Inbound_delivery_number 
from abc.table1;
```

Can we use aggregate functions with boolean function in a Case Statement? Any solution to this ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think window functions should provide the functionality you want.  If I understand correctly, then this produces the results in the question:

```
select t1.*,
       max(erdate) over (partition by ebtype) as max_erdat,
       (case when ebtyp = 'LA'
             then max(v_no) over (partition by ebtyp) 
             else v_no
        end) as Inbound_delivery_number 
from abc.table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding of your needs you didn't put ideal data to present your case so I modified it by changing two `erdat` into higher ones:

```
 ebtyp |   erdat    | v_no
-------+------------+------
 LA    | 2016-09-09 |    4
 AB    | 2016-10-10 |    4
 LA    | 2016-11-11 |    5
 AB    | 2016-11-15 |    6
```

Query:

```
select 
  ebtyp, erdat, v_no, 
  max(case when ebtyp = 'LA' then erdat end) over () as max_erdat, 
  case when ebtyp = 'LA' then max(v_no) over (partition by ebtyp) else v_no end as max_v_no 
from abc.table1;
```

Output:

```
 ebtyp |   erdat    | v_no | max_erdat  | max_v_no
-------+------------+------+------------+----------
 AB    | 2016-10-10 |    4 | 2016-11-11 |        4
 AB    | 2016-11-15 |    6 | 2016-11-11 |        6
 LA    | 2016-09-09 |    4 | 2016-11-11 |        5
 LA    | 2016-11-11 |    5 | 2016-11-11 |        5
```